# Using Windows SBS 2008 with an external DHCP Server

Tags: windows-sbs-2008

Trying to install Windows SBS 2008 on an existing network. It won't let me use the existing DHPC server

During the "Connetct to the Internet" wizard I get

> "An external DHCP Server is running on
>   your network at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,
>   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. Stop the external
>   DHCP Server, and then click Continue
>   to try again."

and it won't let me continue. The problem is that I can't modify the existing network. Any ideas?

Comment: what does the existing network consist of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work around this you need to disconnect the network cable from the SBS 2008 server before running the "Connect to the Internet" wizard.

The wizard will fail when it can't access the Internet.

You will then be able to enter your router information manually in the wizard.
Once you have done this there will be a "Test" button. **Make sure you click this**. This will also fail, but now you will see a "Skip Test" button. Click this to complete the wizard.

Next see my [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/38962/disabling-dhcp-on-sbs-2008/38978#38978) about disabling DHCP on SBS 2008.

Now you can plug the network cable back in.

Comment: Won't this be a problem for Active Directory?

Answer (score 2):

I actually asked the same question recently:  [Disabling DHCP on SBS 2008?](https://serverfault.com/questions/38962/disabling-dhcp-on-sbs-2008)